# Photoelectric-effect laser

Tags: laser

The question is whether it is physically possible to build a laser using only the photoelectric effect in the vacuum, with no lasing material.

I know that there is a whole history of laser development in which people found all sorts of materials that lase if you pump them hard enough, but my question is simpler and more fundamental. Is it really necessary to have a lasing material in order to have a laser?

There already exists a patented optical amplifier using the photoelectric effect in the vacuum, and so I think it should be possible to build a laser, which is basically an optical amplifier between two mirrors. The advantage of such a photoelectric-effect laser is that the applied voltage would allow you to smoothly vary the color of the light produced, instead of relying on a pre-existing electronic-state transition in your gas molecules or a fixed energy band gap in your semiconductor material.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this "amplifier using the photoelectric effect in the vacuum"? Otherwise, how do we know what you're talking about?

Comment: Welcome to the EE.SE!  In addition to agreeing with @ThePhoton, I would also recommend re-formatting your question to make it more clear and obvious what your actual question is.

Comment: http://www.google.com/patents/US8294983

Comment: I can restate it three ways.  Is the photoelectric effect sufficient for a laser?  In other words, why place a lasing material in a laser instead of using the photoelectric effect?  Or, is there a fundamental physical reason why the lasing material is necessary?

Comment: Thanks. I will try Physics SE also. 1 and 2. You are correct, it is more complicated than just the photoelectric effect, although it calls itself "photoelectric effect of surface plasmon resonance electrons", and yes, there is a material. So it's not a great example.  3. Energy is conserved. The electron, in travelling from the cathode to the anode, loses electrical potential energy. That's the energy that would go into the production of the new photon. A possible answer might be that there exists no quantum process that would produce the new photon?

Comment: I don't know what you talk about energy conserved, is doesn't seem to me connected with the lasing. For obtaining the laser beam we need many atoms raised to a certain excited energy level. This is why we need the material, and why we do pumping. Now, the trigger that starts the lasing is the emission of one or more photons spontaneously. In travelling through the material they make the other atoms emit also, and all this gross emission is *in phase*. I am no specialist in lasers, but this is the main picture. Now, what can be the similarity between the photoelectric effect and the above?

Comment: Agree with Sophia - I don't see how the setup you describe would produce a lasing effect - what would play the role of an inverted population that could be stimulated to emit coherent photons?

Comment: Hi Sofia and Brionius. Is there a single-electron stimulated-emission process in the vacuum, when the electron travels from the cathode to the anode? The electron loses eV, where V is the applied voltage, and this energy might produce a photon of visible light. That is, unless there is some rule of quantum mechanics that excludes this stimulated-emission process. What is that rule? Why can't the photoelectric effect alone result in the stimulated emission of a new photon? "What would play the role of an inverted population?" The electons in the cathode at higher potential than the anode.

Comment: Notice in the linked patent, there is a layer of "organic dye" or "semiconductor material". This material is "excited". I believe this is where the stimulated emission is going on in the patented design, but I cannot follow patent-ese well enough to be sure.

Comment: Hi Photon. I believe that the patented device is probably irrelevant to my basic question, but I can't be sure because of the "patent-ese". The basic question is whether it is necessary to have a dye, a gas or a semiconductor in order to have a stimulated-emission process. The process I am imagining would take an electron from the cathode across the vacuum to the anode, giving its energy to the production of a new photon. All surfaces would be highly reflective, including the cathode and anode. There might be some basic physical reason why this can't happen, but I just don't know what it is.

Comment: There is a question on EE Stack Exchange “Photoelectric effect vacuum tube” http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96554/photoelectric-effect-vacuum-tube  That question has to do with using the photoelectric effect to excite cathode electrons rather than heating. The answer seems to be that it's possible. So in my imaged laser, the ambient bath of photons reflecting bath and forth in the optical cavity would excite the cathode electrons to the vacuum level and create a current between the cathode and the anode. The only remaining question is, could photons be produced?

Comment: The answer probably has to do with the absence of a resonance between the incoming photon and the electron moving across the vacuum. In a free-electron laser, resonance is created by spatially modulating the magnetic field. And the cross section for stimulated emission involves the spectral line width, i.e. the quality of the resonance. No resonance implies no stimulated emission.  An electron hitting the anode dumps its energy into the metal as phonons and photons, i.e. heat.

Answer (score 1):

There exists the [free electron laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser)

> A free-electron laser (FEL), is a kind of laser whose lasing medium consists of very-high-speed electrons moving freely through a magnetic structure, hence the term free electron. The free-electron laser is tunable and has the widest frequency range of any laser type, currently ranging in wavelength from microwaves, through terahertz radiation and infrared, to the visible spectrum, ultraviolet, and X-ray.

The magnetic structure generates the coherence in the photons produced.

Maybe with nanotechnology the design can be miniaturized by using a photoelectric source ( which I suppose will in any case be the source of the electrons in the FEL  beam)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question is basically the generation of laser via electron impact. The basic principle behind laser radiation which makes it coherent is stimulated emission of photons in population reversed media. If you have free electrons (whether thermionic or via photo electric effect) and you accelerate it to certain voltage then make it fall on a material, it will certainly generate a radiation. This is a basic principle behind the x ray tubes. However the radiation will not be coherent because each atom will generate photons according it its own phase and the coherence (which is gained by stimulated emission) will be lost. The duration of this radiation is a convolution of the lifetime of the transition level and the duration of electron pulse.

It may also be noted here that the spectrum will not be narrow band (like laser) in this case and only the characteristic x rays generated in this process have narrow band spectrum and this is again incoherent radiation.

The broad spectrum is due to the fact that electron do not loose its energy in one impact but it rather looses its energy continuously in several impacts. The radiation generated in this process is both Bremsstrahlung and line radiations.